# Fields of Probability Proof

Tags: probability

Let F be a field. Show that
(A \ C) \ (B \ C) = (A \ B) \ C, ∀A, B, C ∈ F

I know that (A\C) = $(A\cap C^c)$ 
and that (B\C) = $(B\cap C^c)$

so (A \ C) \ (B \ C) = $(A\cap C^c)$\ $(B\cap C^c)$

$(A\cap C^c)$\ $(B\cap C^c)$ = $(A\cap C^c)\cap(B\cap C^c)^c$

$(B\cap C^c)^c$ = $(1 - (B\cap C^c)$

$(A\cap C^c)\cap(1 - (B\cap C^c))$

Using the law of Associativity this is equal to $(A\cap(1 - (B\cap C^c))\cap(C^c)$

The final answer is equal to $(A\cap B^c)\cap(C^c)$ which matches what I have on the left but the right does not seem right at all can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your solution except in presentation.

I'd write it more like this:

$$\begin{align}\quad&(A\setminus C)\setminus (B\setminus C)
\\=&(A\cap C^\complement)\cap(B\cap C^\complement)^\complement&\text{definition of set difference}
\\=&A\cap (C^\complement\cap(B\cap C^\complement)^\complement)&\text{association}
\\=&A\cap(C^\complement\cap(B^\complement\cup C)) &\text{de Morgan's Laws for sets}
\\=&A\cap (B^\complement\cap C^\complement)&\text{absorption}
\\=&(A\cap B^\complement)\cap C^\complement&\text{association}\\=&(A\setminus B)\setminus C&\text{definition of set difference}\end{align}$$